# Laravel 5.4 - Write and use multiple scripts

Tags: javascript, laravel-5, assets

I want to know where I should write my js files in **Laravel 5.4** for compiling after this files.

Example:

I want to create a **test.js** file with a `console.log('Hello World)`. Where I create this file ? Have I put it in the `resources/assets/js/app.js` folder ?

My example code:

Folder `resources/assets/js/app.js` :

```
require('./bootstrap');
require('./normalscripts/test');
window.Vue = require('vue');

/**
 * Next, we will create a fresh Vue application instance and attach it to
 * the page. Then, you may begin adding components to this application
 * or customize the JavaScript scaffolding to fit your unique needs.
 */

Vue.component('example', require('./components/Example.vue'));

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app'
});
```

In `resources/assets/js/normalscripts/test` I put `console.log('WORKS');`

And in the view I loaded app.js from public folder

Other question I have is, if I want to load some differents scripts depending of the html view that I am using, how can I can configure them in the app.js for this ?

Example:

I have test1.js and test2.js. I want to load in the view1.html the test1.js and in the view2.html the test2.js. How could I do this ?

Thanks

Comment: I follow the docs and I couldnt make the example that I have described above

Answer (score 0):

As docs says: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/structure

> The Public Directory
>
> The public directory contains the index.php file, which is the entry
>   point for all requests entering your application. This directory also
>   houses your assets such as images, JavaScript, and CSS.

Javascript files must be stored on the public directory, after knowing this, one of the possible correct path would be:

```
app/public/js/compiled/app.js
```

And you can include to the JavaScript file on your views like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/compiled/app.js') }}"></script>
```

Laravel 5.4 is prepared to work with Vue.js, by default you need to have your js files on your assets folder, after compiling them they will be outputted at the public folder.

In case you are using another JS framework **you need to indicate the path for the compiled JS files**, it should be pointing to the public folder.

Comment: Yes, but I want to compile my js files from resources/assets/js/app.js. The generated file is the app.js that will be in the public directory.

Comment: @Aceconhielo You need configure your JS framework to indicate the path you want to place the compiled js, it should be on the public folder :)

Comment: ok but webpack.mix.js make this I think with the line mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js')

Comment: @Aceconhielo You can read about it there: https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-elixir-webpack-official

Answer (score 0):

The [Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/frontend#writing-javascript) answers your question:

> By default, the Laravel webpack.mix.js file compiles your SASS and the  resources/assets/js/app.js file. Within the app.js file you may register your Vue components or, if you prefer a different framework, configure your own JavaScript application. Your compiled JavaScript will typically be placed in the public/js directory.